# Saving data for only one user with using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, electron

I'm developing electron app and using Firebase Database. I created database user by user but saving data for everyone. I want to save data also separate for the user ID.

I can create a user under their user IDs but cannot write their data under their user IDs.

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$location){
$scope.signup = function(){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.mail,$scope.parola).then(sonuc=>{
        console.log(sonuc.user);
        return db.collection('users').doc(sonuc.user.uid).set({
            inputQ: $scope.inputQ
        }).then( ()=> {
            console.log('deneme basarili');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    })
}

$scope.login = function(){
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.mail,$scope.parola).then(sonuc=> {
        $location.path('/dashboard')
    })
}
```

});

This part successfully creates a user under its user ID.

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.add = function() {
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).add({
        baslik: $scope.baslik,
        icerik: $scope.icerik
    }).then( ()=> {
        console.log('ekleme basarili');
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.message);
    })
}
```

This part cannot create data under its user ID.

The error is user is not defined.

Comment: what is the user.uid value in the second part? Try swapping the variable out with a test uid and see if it works.

Comment: What are your security rules? These govern permissions, in terms of what you can and cannot write/read/update/delete

Comment: @Uzer I checked the security rules, every user can read&write. The problem about Javascript. I can't write the correct code.

Comment: @NathanLevitt I tried to catch user ID and save some text under that User ID.

Comment: In one method you uses "set" and say it works, in your other method you use "add". Trying using "set" for both

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.add = function() {
        db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            baslik: $scope.baslik,
            icerik: $scope.icerik
        }).then( ()=> {
            console.log('ekleme basarili');
        }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.message);
    })
}
```

Trying using "set" rather than "add", "add" is usually reserved for adding to a collection where it creates the records identifier for you, without you having to provide it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I still get the same error. User is not defined. In my opinion, js cannot catch the user ID. How can I catch it at that line?

Answer (score 0):

You should change `.add` to `.set` but also make sure to include `merge: true` to prevent an override to the document (e.x. if there is a current document it will update it and if there is no document it will create one).

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.add = function() {
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(
      {
        .
        .
        .
      },
      { merge: true }
    ).then( ()=> {

    }).catch(err=>{

    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I still get the same error. User is not defined. In my opinion, js cannot catch the user ID. How can I catch it at that line?

Comment: What is the user ID returning at the moment? If the user is not defined the problem is in the code getting the user data.

Comment: Every time I created a user. It created under users folder with its user ID in the firebase. I tried to write values under this user ID to make every value private for every user. If I don't explain correctly I can add you to the project on the GitHub. I am very new at Electron and Firebase.

Comment: Can you upload the code on how you are getting the 'user' variable that you are using for 'user.uid' because I don't think it is returning the correct value.

Comment: app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$location){
    $scope.signup = function(){
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.mail,$scope.parola).then(sonuc=>{
            console.log(sonuc.user);
            return db.collection('users').doc(sonuc.user.uid).set({
                inputQ: $scope.inputQ
            }).then( ()=> {
                console.log('deneme basarili');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
            })
        })
    }

Comment: This code gets the correct user ID and create folder in the database

Comment: user.uid is not a global variable, if you want to use that variable in your function you have to pass it in.

Comment: are you trying to do this for the current user (like the user is signed in already)?